# Add language to Windows XP automatically

Tags: windows-xp, script, language, input-languages

I want to automate a process due to the number of computers I have. The problem is that I need to add languages to a large number of XP systems so I can type using French or Arabic keyboards without repeating the same process every time. Maybe a batch script would help, or even a simple program written in C or Python (I can develop using those languages) and maybe this screenshot can emphasize the problem:

[image]